# Android | JAVA | Cannot Access Variable returned by a method

Tags: java, android, methods

I have a system of arduino which sends back "1" when browsing "10.0.0.1/connection". I am storing that "1" into a variable called 'value' and accessing it in another method. While accessing value in another method it gives null pointer exception.

**Description :**

This is the method which loads url and store's whatever source code i receive into a variable.

```
public String getConnection()
    {
        String []value = new String[1];
        String con = "http://10.0.0.1/connection";
        Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load(con).asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(result);
                conFlag = i;
                tv.setText(result);
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(i == 1){
                    value[0] = result;
                Log.d("vol ",value[0]);
              }
            }
        });
    return value[0];
    }
```

Here as you can see I printed log which will print `value[0]` if `i==1`. And I set `conFlag = i`.

Here I am getting the value which is returned by `getConnection()`

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        Log.d("onRequestPermissionsResult() ->", " called");
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Log.d("onRequestPermissionsResult() ->", " requestCode = 1");
            if (grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //do your thing
                info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                if (info.getSSID().trim().equals(ssid)){
                    String conct = getConnection();
                    Log.d("vol conct", conct);
                    if (conFlag == 1){
                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("Value","Not found");
          
                }
                Log.d("onRequestPermissionsResult() ->", " Permissions Granted");

            }
        }

    }
```

Here I am getting exception of nullPointer on "Log.d("vol conct", conct);".
**Logs**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ims_temp_1, PID: 6670
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.ims_temp_1/com.example.ims_temp_1.SplashScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5184)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2222)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:155)
        at com.example.ims_temp_1.SplashScreen.onRequestPermissionsResult(SplashScreen.java:88)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:8458)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8308)
```

If I don't call the method `getConnection()` and do not use it's returned value then it is printing Log of `value[0]` as `1`. Which means whatever string i received is parsed as int and compared with `int 1`. I am not able to use that `i` or `conFlag` in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method.

Comment: getConnection() return null because Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load(con) runs on background thread.

Comment: then What should I do?

Comment: create an interface and pass that on getConnection method.

Comment: Sorry to ask but, Can you please elaborate. I don't it. If possible explain it with code please. You can post as answer and then if that doesn't work you can edit the answer.

Comment: I have posted a full solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface for Result like this:

```
public interface ResultCallback {
    public void result(String value);
}
```

update your getConnection method like this:

```
public void getConnection(ResultCallback callback)
    {
        String []value = new String[1];
        String con = "http://10.0.0.1/connection";
        Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load(con).asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(result);
                conFlag = i;
                tv.setText(result);
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(i == 1){
                    value[0] = result;
                    Log.d("vol ",value[0]);
                    callback.result(value[0]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and your onRequestPermissionsResult like this:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        Log.d("onRequestPermissionsResult() ->", " called");
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Log.d("onRequestPermissionsResult() ->", " requestCode = 1");
            if (grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //do your thing
                info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                if (info.getSSID().trim().equals(ssid)){
                    getConnection(new ResultCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void result(String value) {
                            Log.d("vol conct", value);
                            if (conFlag == 1){
                                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("Value","Not found");

                }
                Log.d("onRequestPermissionsResult() ->", " Permissions Granted");

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ErselanKhan. This code is working as expected. But, If i want to learn about what this code did then what should I search for? Do i search for "interface callback" or "implementing interface" or something else?

Comment: you should learn the "Callback Functions"